# How to make the background visible?

Tags: html, css

I have a simple code for a simple webpage, but it does not work: for some reason, the background is not displayed. I checked everything in different browsers on different computers. Where do you think there might be a mistake?

```css
.section--map {
 padding: 40px 0; 

 background: #e6e6e6 url("../images/map-bg.jpg") center no-repeat;
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover; 
}
```

```html
<section class="section  section--map">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="map">
            <div class="map__title">
                <div><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i></div>
                <a href="https://goo.gl/maps/XmN4jh6RPPij7qy46" target="_blank"><h2>Open Map</h2></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Do you get any console errors? Is the image path correct?

Comment: Yes, I checked everything many times. It seems that no errors are written anywhere, but visually the background is not present on the page.

Comment: worked fine for me   https://jsfiddle.net/b8h4Lpo9/

Comment: Thank you Bryan! Indeed, your code runs on a jsfiddle.net website. Maybe there is a problem only in the Chrome browser?!

Comment: @RachelGallen did you read it? "worked fine for me jsfiddle.net/b8h4Lpo9 – Bryan Dellinger 9 hours ago" He listed both a colour and an image in the background attributes, and it works perfect.

Comment: @RachelGallen a few hours ago you said that we can’t writing both the background color and the picture for the background at the same time. Now you are talking about a completely different thing: now you think that the problem is in absolute and relative URLs.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if path to your image is correct or it might be that your image type is .jpeg?

Comment: Yes, I checked everything many times. Moreover, the same thing works in the video clip for one good youtuber.